# How to secure AppScript against other Editors

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to secure my custom functions in App Script. I saw that I need to create my own Add-on for that, but I don't have any idea how I can do it and what I need. Did I need a Google Workspace to for my own Add-on?

Comment: What kind of specific security or restrictions are you looking to implement for your custom functions?

Comment: Just  don't want to show other editors my code from custom functions